# How to dump a core file TEXT pages as disassembled text file?

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump

I have a core file and I want to dump all the executable memory pages it contains to a ascii file to follow the assembler that gets executed. How can I do so ?

Comment: By default core file does not contain program if I am right: http://linux.die.net/man/5/core.

Comment: @skwllsp: it contains a dump of all the VM pages in use, which includes executable sections.

Answer (score 3):

I found it. objdump is the tool I need. The option -d in particular disassembles the core file contents. I didn't know objdump also handled core files.

Comment: Note that a `core` file *usually* does not contain any (read-only) executable pages.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Yes, I realized that I created the core not automatically out of a crash, but I used gdb to dump it.